# Multiplication in jQuery dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, multiplication

I am trying to make a multiplication function in jquery where which helps change the default value-based output.

For example - if I type the `input#mainInput` value then it will change all the inputs value base own his `default value * input#mainInput` and if the `value == 'NaN'` it will do dirent funcion.

Please help me how to I make this function in jQuery.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input#mainInput', function() {
  thisParentQtyValueBox = $(this).val();

  daughtersBoxValueAttr = $("input.input__bom").attr("inputid");

  daughtersBoxValue = $("input#daughterInput_" + daughtersBoxValueAttr).val();

  $("input#daughterInput_" + daughtersBoxValueAttr).val(thisParentQtyValueBox * daughtersBoxValue);

  if ($("input#daughterInput_" + daughtersBoxValueAttr) == 'Nan') {
    $("input#daughterInput_" + daughtersBoxValueAttr).val('3' * daughtersBoxValue)
  }
});

//If
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mainInput" type="text" placeholder="Number" />
<br><br>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_1" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="1" value="5" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_2" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="2" value="10" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_3" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="3" value="15" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_4" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="4" value="20" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_5" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="5" value="25" /><br/>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to store the default value in the data attr so then it will not multiple by result value and it will multiple by your default value. for dynamic multiplication, you can use jquery `each`. check below code.

```js
$(document).on('input', 'input#mainInput', function() {
  thisParentQtyValueBox = parseInt( $(this).val() );
  if( Number.isNaN( thisParentQtyValueBox ) ){
    thisParentQtyValueBox = 3;
  }
  $('.input__bom').each(function(){
    $(this).val( thisParentQtyValueBox * $(this).data('value') );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mainInput" type="text" placeholder="Number" />
<br><br>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_1" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="1" data-value ="5" value="5" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_2" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="2" data-value ="10" value="10" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_3" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="3" data-value ="15" value="15" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_4" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="4" data-value ="20" value="20" /><br/>
<input class="input__bom" id="daughterInput_5" type="text" placeholder="value" inputid="5" data-value ="25" value="25" /><br/>
```

Comment: can you tell me test cases? which input are you entering?

Comment: When I am tying the number in `#mainInput` there is not changing the multiplied value in other all textboxes. for changing, there is required to click backspace key. overall the output not changing live..

Comment: Did you check the above snippet? value changes on input changes.

Comment: keyup is not a good event for this. Input can be changed by other things than the keyboard. Should be the input event. Also, there is no need for event delegation here. The `if` condition should not be in the loop. It just does not do anything useful the second, third time it runs. The HTML has a bunch of attributes that are not useful. I addressed all those things in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when the input is not a number, you want to do as if the input was 3.

Some issues in your code:

- `$("input.input__bom").attr("inputid")` is always going to evaluate to 1, as only the *first* matching element is used. And it is strange to use this attribute value to then retrieve that element again via its `id` property.
- You would need a loop somewhere so to visit each of the "input__bom" elements.
- `== 'Nan` is never going to be true. You should in fact test the main input itself to see if it represents a valid number. For that you can use `isNaN`.
- It is a bad idea to give these elements a unique id attribute. You can use jQuery to visit them each and deal with them. There is no need for such `id` attribute.
- Don't use the `keyup` event for this, as input can be given in other ways than pressing keys (e.g. dragging text with mouse, or using the context menu to paste). Use the `input` event instead.
- There is no good reason to use event delegation here on `$(document)`. Just bind your listener directly the main input element.
- Declare your variables with `var` (or `let`, `const`). It is bad practice to no do that (it makes your variables global).
- It seems like the 5 "bom" input elements are not really intended for *input*, but for output. In that case the `placeholder` attribute makes no sense, and they should better be marked with the `readonly` attribute.

```js
$("#mainInput").on('input', function() {
    var mainInput = $(this).val();
    var multiplier = +mainInput; // convert to number with unary +
    // default value in case input is not a valid number, or is empty
    if (Number.isNaN(multiplier) || !mainInput) {
        multiplier = 3; 
    }
    $('.input__bom').each(function() {
        $(this).val( multiplier * $(this).data('value') );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mainInput" type="text" placeholder="Number" />
<br><br>
<input class="input__bom" type="text" readonly data-value="5" value="5"><br/>
<input class="input__bom" type="text" readonly data-value="10" value="10"><br/>
<input class="input__bom" type="text" readonly data-value="15" value="15"><br/>
<input class="input__bom" type="text" readonly data-value="20" value="20"><br/>
<input class="input__bom" type="text" readonly data-value="25" value="25" /><br/>
```

Comment: the number is not changing while input changing `#mainInput` there is need to input `backspace`

Comment: I don't know what you did, but if I run the snippet above, the changes are immediate with every change to the main input. Of course, the input must be a number to get anything else than the default 15/30/45/60/75 output. Are you sure you copied the code (JavaScript and HTML) correctly?

Comment: When I am tying the number in `#mainInput` there is not changing the multiplied value in other all textboxes. for changing, there is required to click backspace key. overall the output not changing live..

Comment: That is not true. Please run the snippet above. Are you running the snippet here or your own copy? Which is your browser? Although this works on all modern browsers.